# Create folders by file extension

Tags: batch-file

I a using this code to create folders from files by their extension

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%i in (*) do (   
   set "x=%%~xi"   
   set x=!x:~1,400!  
   mkdir "!x!"
   move "%%i" "!x!" 
)  
pause
```

I need to make letters capital

Comment: What's with `set x=!x:~1,400!`? Do you expect extensions to be larger than 400 chars? To just remove the dot, `set x=!x:~1` is sufficient.

Comment: And how to capitalize the letters?

Comment: @xeex - [manually](https://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringOperations.php#Function.toUpper), basically

Comment: But also, Windows is case-insensitive so the .jpg files and .JPG files will end up in the same folder.

Comment: Thank you for help, I have seen a batch file done that does exactly what I am looking for, creates folders by file extension and capitalizes the names as well.